# cannot convert 'double (*)[4]' to 'double**' in assignment

Tags: c++, pointers

I was following a tutorial  [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_dynamic_memory.htm). I came across the following lines of code.

```
double** pvalue  = NULL;      // Pointer initialized with null 
pvalue  = new double [3][4];  // Allocate memory for a 3x4 array
```

When I compiled it, it is throwing an error

> "cannot convert 'double (*)[4]' to 'double**' in assignment"

Is the code invalid? or I'm doing something wrong.Also, please, if possible, describe how could I declare pointer to multi dimension array?

Comment: Since you are programming in C++, I'd use `vector<vector<double>>`.

Comment: It is a mistake in the tutorial example .

Comment: For the record, `double**` is expecting a pointer (which possible points to an array) to a pointer (which, again, possibly points to an array) of doubles. So, an array of pointers to arrays of doubles. Whereas `new double[3][4]` makes an array of 12 consecutive doubles, with some type-system magic to make it look like a nested array.

Comment: You could do `struct Array3x4 { double value[3][4]; };` and then `auto pvalue = new Array3x4;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not do it. `double [3][4];` allocates a flat memory of 3 arrays `double[4]`. The tutorial has the error.

```
using d4 = double [4];
// or typedef double d4[4];
d4* pvalue  = nullptr;
pvalue  = new double [3][4];
delete[] pvalue;
```

Comment: Did you compile your code? I complied and it throws an error **error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'double'** on first line `using d4 = double [4] ;`

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari Sure I compiled it. Your compiler seems is old. Try to sepecify `-std=c++14` or `-std=c++11`. Or replace this line with `typedef double d4[4];`.

Comment: Here is build log. 
-------------- Build: Debug in Prac (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)-------

`mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g -std=c++14 -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW" -c "C:\Users\Sujeet Agrahari\Desktop\Prac\main.cpp" -o obj\Debug\main.o
mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\Prac.exe obj\Debug\main.o   
C:\Users\Sujeet Agrahari\Desktop\Prac\main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
C:\Users\Sujeet Agrahari\Desktop\Prac\main.cpp:7:10: error: expected nested-name-specifier before 'double'
    using double d4 = double [4];`

Comment: Sorry, My fault. It was not workign before I switched to -std=c++14. So I thought maybe altering the code would help(specifying the type). After you suggest to use -std=c++14. I did that, but forgot to change the code, sorry man! It is working now.

Comment: I don't have that much knowledge. Your code seems cleaner way to  do this. First, help me to understand it, I'll happily accept your answer. :)
What I get from your  is - You are making a type definition for d4 which is type of double of 4 consecutive chunks of memory. 
In second line, you are making a pointer "pvalue" to this type of variables. But I don't get this line:  `pvalue  = new double [3][4];`, help me, please?

Comment: Ok. It is a known difficulty of understanding expressions like `new double [3][4]`. The key point is that first square braces are applicable to `new` and other square braces are applicable to type. So the expression should be read like: *please allocate 3 arrays of double elements, so each array consists of 4 doubles.* I introduced `d4` to make code clearer. Without it I would write `double (* parray)[4] = nullptr`. * is for parray and [4] is for type double.

Comment: ..and pvalue points to first of them ( the array of first four double type of memory chunks) right?

Answer (score 1):

This `pvalue  = new double [3][4];` is not correct. Find how to allocate memory for 2D array using `new`. May be you want like below.

```
int main(void) {
        double** pvalue  = NULL;        
        /* first allocate for pvalue */  
        pvalue  = new double *[3];  
        for(int col = 0; col < 3 ; col++ )
                /* allocate for each palue element */
                pvalue[col] = new double [4];
        return 0;
}
```

Once done, don't forget to  free the dynamically allocated memory  by calling `delete`.

Comment: where is the `col<4` ? haha ;)

Comment: Your are using a for loop just to allocate the memory. Suppose, I want a larger dimension, won't that cause any problem? Also, using new multiple times don't seem proper to me. There must be a simple way to achieve this..

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari a `vector` will be very simple. Since you want to allocate memory by yourself, this is the only way.

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari more specific, an array cannot decay twice, which means use a double** to "take" double[][] is invalid, but if you use double[]*, it may seems to be more simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. If you must allocate memory by yourself, try:

```
double** pt=nullptr;
pt=new double[3];
for(std::size_t i=0;i<3;++i)
    pt[i]=new double[4];
```

the deletion is a reverse process of allocation.

And one thing you need to notice is that you shouldn't use `range-based for` `non-member begin and end function` or `sizeof operator` since `pt` is **not** an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep allocation of the two dimensional array,

```
  new double [3][4]
```

there are two way to refer to this memory chunk,
1.,

```
  double* pvalue  = NULL;
  pvalue  = (double*)new double [3][4];
```

and 2.,

```
  double (* parray)[4] = NULL;
  parray = new double [3][4];
```

if you want to keep the pointer-to-pointer variable, i.e., `double** ppvalue`, then,

```
  double** ppvalue  = NULL;
  ppvalue = new double*[3];     (a)
  for(int i =0; i<3; i++)
      ppvalue[i]=new double[4]; (b)
```

basically, you need to allocate memory for the array of pointers(a), and populate those pointers with concrete addresses.

The code you posted

```
double** pvalue  = NULL;      // Pointer initialized with null 
pvalue  = new double [3][4];  // Allocate memory for a 3x4 array
```

does not work because there is no way it can deduct the offset of `pvalue`, though it looks very nice and clear.

I also paste the full testing code so you can have a play:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  double* pvalue  = NULL;
  pvalue  = (double*)new double [3][4];

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      *(pvalue+i*4+j) = (double)i*(double)j;
      printf("%f\n", *(pvalue+i*4+j));
    }
  }

  double (* parray)[4] = NULL;
  parray = new double [3][4];

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      parray[i][j] = (double)i*(double)j;
      printf("%f\n", parray[i][j]);
    }
  }

  double** ppvalue  = NULL;
  ppvalue = new double*[3];
  for(int i =0; i<3; i++)
      ppvalue[i]=new double[4];

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      ppvalue[i][j] = (double)i*(double)j;
      printf("%f\n", ppvalue[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the compiler explicitly told you, `new double [3][4]` evaluates to a pointer of `double (*)[4]` type

```
double (*pvalue)[4] = new double [3][4];
```

You can't store that value in a `double **` pointer.

P.S. The "tutorial" you linked is just nonsensical garbage.